How to export data using PyQGIS with displayed values instead of raw values?
I'm using QGIS 3.34. I am trying to develop a plugin for my company's users to export all data (many different feature layers) within a selected polygon. I need to export a Vector Layer to Shapefile using the displayed values instead of the raw values.  I know there is an option for this in the export UI, but I have not gotten this to work with PyQGIS VectorFileWriterV3. I have tried the FieldValueConverter option, but QGIS crashes every time.
The data is from a SQL server where the problem fields are integers. The display values are referenced in QGIS using ValueRelation to some foreign key tables.
Here's what I've tried.
This crashes every time. I've tried the output as both f'{output}\\site' and f'{output}\\site.shp'.
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()    
options.driverName = "ESRI Shapefile"
options.encoding = 'utf-8'
options.onlySelectedFeatures = True
options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteFile
options.fieldValueConverter = QgsVectorFileWriter.FieldValueConverter()
transform_context = QgsProject.instance().transformContext()
error = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3(inputlayer, f'{output}\\site', transform_context, options)
if error[0] == QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:
    print("success again!")
else:
    print(error)

I've also tried the solution from this link.
This solution does produce the output file without an error message, but the attribute values still appear as integers rather than the string display values.
layer = someQGSVectorLayerwithSelectedFeatures
class CustomFieldValueConverter(QgsVectorFileWriter.FieldValueConverter):

    def __init__(self, layer):
        QgsVectorFileWriter.FieldValueConverter.__init__(self)
        self.layer = layer

    def fieldDefinition(self, field):
        return field

    def convert(self, idx, value):
        return value

    def clone(self):
        return FieldValueConverter(self)

layer = iface.activeLayer()

options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
myconverter = CustomFieldValueConverter(layer)
options.fieldValueConverter = myconverter
options.driverName = "ESRI Shapefile"
options.encoding = 'utf-8'
options.onlySelectedFeatures = True
options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteFile
context = QgsProject.instance().transformContext()
error_message = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3(layer, mypath, context, options)

I have made sure that I can export the data using the UI, and that works just fine, but I do need a scripted solution. I need to select and export 9 layers which have several fields each with ValueRelations.
